# Storing Emoji character in AWS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, emoji, utf8mb4

I'm having an Amazon Web Services hosted Spring + Hibernate application that's using a standard MySQL database. The application serves as a backend for an iPhone application. I'm trying to store Emoji characters entered on the iPhone in the MySQL database. I've done some research and found out that it requires 4 byte UTF-8 storage, which is supported since MySQL 5.5 with the utf8mb4 character set. However, this is not yet supported by AWS as an option in the Group Parameters.

I'm looking for a good work around that still makes this possible. I know that one work around is storing the text as BLOB in the database but then I can no longer perform text queries on that text.

Answer (score 0):

utf8mb4 support is dependent on the mysql version that you use.

check if the following works

```
create database test
default character set utf8mb4;
```

If this doesn't give you an error you are good to go. If it does, you might need to upgrade your mysql.

Once that is set right, you can go about upgrading the tables and columns that need to move up from utf8 to utf8mb4.

Comment: I'm using MySQL in an AWS hosted environment. I don't have direct control of the database.

Comment: You can set the character set per table and even per column, it need not be set at the database level.